# SQL - OVER and ORDERBY

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I don't understand OVER very well, and I wanted to clarify what this does what I think it does.

If I have a provided Sort type, record Status, and a Meeting Date:

I would like to sort by MeetingDate by default.
I would like to sort by Status when sort type is 2, *and then by Meeting Date.*

Does the below code do this? My testing indicates it does, but I could be missing something.

```
SELECT Foo.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY 
            CASE @SortType WHEN 2 THEN Foo.FK_Status END ASC,
            Foo.MeetingDate DESC
    ) AS RowOrder
```

More specifically, if @SortType is 1 does is it appropriate to believe the code breaks down as:

```
SELECT Foo.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY 
            ASC,
            Foo.MeetingDate DESC
    ) AS RowOrder
```

Which I think might break down to just:

```
SELECT Foo.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY 
            Foo.MeetingDate DESC
    ) AS RowOrder
```

As opposed to (when @SortType is 2):

```
  SELECT Foo.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY 
            Foo.FK_Status ASC,
            Foo.MeetingDate DESC
    ) AS RowOrder
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CASE @SortType WHEN 2 THEN Foo.FK_Status END` is equivalent to `CASE @SortType WHEN 2 THEN Foo.FK_Status ELSE NULL END`. In other words, if @SortType = 1 then the query effectively is this:

```
SELECT Foo.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY 
            NULL ASC,
            Foo.MeetingDate DESC
    ) AS RowOrder
```

Answer (score 1):

The `RowOrder` column will be in the *sequence* described, but without an `order by` clause at the end of the query, there is no guarantee in what order the rows will be sorted.

So:

```
SELECT Foo.*,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
                          CASE @SortType WHEN 2 THEN Foo.FK_Status END ASC,
                          Foo.MeetingDate DESC) AS RowOrder
FROM Foo;
```

- could appear in any order, while:

```
SELECT Foo.*
FROM Foo
ORDER BY CASE @SortType WHEN 2 THEN Foo.FK_Status END ASC, Foo.MeetingDate DESC;
```

- will order the output in the sort order described (without including a RowOrder column).